# Efficient way to fire 2 diff events with the same button on each click?

Tags: c#, button

I have a C# button, let's say 'ON/OFF':

I want to change 'OFF', when we first click it and run buttonOFF()
When we click again, it changes to 'ON' and run buttonON()

and so on..

What's the correct way to do that? Can I do it all in one onClick event? peace of small example would be useful. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void buttonON()
{
    // Magic here
}

private void buttonOFF()
{
    // Magic here
}

protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( button.Text == "ON" )
    {
        button.Text = "OFF";
        this.buttonOFF();
    }
    else
    {
        button.Text = "ON";
        this.buttonON();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I though I should smth with -+ removing and ++ adding events recursively. But this will work

Comment: But if i don't want change Text of my button?

Comment: This might be improved by leveraging a state variable instead of checking the button text; but if you don't have i18n to worry about, this is definitely clear and concise

Comment: If you decide to change text of the button you need to remember to change it in the code too

Comment: what to do, if instead using button, I am using ImageButton, where button.text is unavailable ?

Comment: @Tomasusa - change the image? Honestly, it's up to you. Modify the button as you want. Is the pattern here really so non-obvious?

Answer (score 5):

You might best using [this](http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=797) method. Using a checkbox with a button appearance

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox(); 
checkBox1.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution works, I think there's an issue with the UI.  Consider this:

As a user I'm looking at a button, the button says "Off".  Does this represent state or action?  Is it on and by clicking I'll turn it off?  Or is it off and by clicking I'll turn it on?  Also, what am I turning on/off? The UI is somewhat ambiguous unless I have experience and have learned what it means.

However, if you were to use something like the checkbox appearance suggested by Dean and label the button (checkbox), say, "Engine", both the state and the purpose are clear:

[image]

Comment: on/off was just an example .. more informative text will be on the button. Thanks anyway, good catch here